# Fetching Test Executions status with REST API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-xray

I am fetching test and their status attached to test execution using API. Below is the command for same:

```
curl -u username:password -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" --url ""https://server/rest/api/2/testexec/TEST-1161""
```

I am facing below error while fetching the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><status><status-code>404</status-code><message>null for uri: https://server/rest/api/2/testexec/TEST-1161</message></status>
```

Where I am getting wrong ?? Also When I am using the same url for updating status of TEST, I am able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

On your request you are missing the last '/test' that is originating the 404 error.

Add it to the end of your URL, for example:
`curl -u username:password -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" --url ""https://server/rest/api/2/testexec/TEST-1161/test""`

You have documentation available here regarding how to get Test Execution details from Xray: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Test+Executions+-+REST.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for replying. I trying with your suggested way. But I am still getting this error.

Comment: The URL is the last parameter received and do not need the "--url" or the double quotes. My suggestion is to remove the --url and the double quotes.Make sure that the endpoint you are replacing "server" in the URL is available and reachable and that the Test key exists in your Jira project.